# How to defer external javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, pagespeed

Recently I had to increase pagespeed and website performance. One of the main tools for the job is of course `async` and deffering javascript. **However** I've noticed that the biggest scripts are external ones, the ones loaded from external sources.

My question is:

Is there a way to defer .js scripts of external source?

**EDIT**

Ok, so maybe I should've clarified. The external js is loaded by a plugin of a cms, namely wordpress. I can't put the script at the end of the page and I can't use `<script src="demo.js" defer></script>` 
Any other ideas?

I'm not very well versed in javascript, I was hoping there's some js magic that can make sure that a script gets loaded after the page, even if I can't interfere with the code that originally loads it (cause it'll get overwritten with another upload, cause it can mess plugin mechanics and cause of bunch of other reasons).

Comment: start by putting your JS files at the end of the page?

Comment: also try not hit the same domain for scripts more than 2 or three times since the browser will limit concurrent requests to the same domain. use cdn's instead

Comment: `<script src="demo_defer.js" defer></script>` **defer** does not fit your requirements?